# extract and sum two "slash" separated numbers e.g (50/20 = 70) in php?

Tags: php

I have this two digit number i.e. 50/20 which is seperated by slash and stored in one column of database.

```
$value = '50/20';
```

I want to get separate number as

```
$num1 = 50;
$num2 = 20;
```

and sum as

```
$sum = $num1+$num2;
```

Is there any solution for to separate those combine numbers.

Comment: Are you dealing with a *string*? If so, please add quotes around your inputs and outputs, as it currently appears that you're trying to reverse division of two numbers.

Comment: You can just split this in to two integrers

Comment: @meagar Seeing as OP says it comes from a database, I can only assume it is in fact, a string

Answer (score 5):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Try like this

```
$value  = '50/20';
$arr    = explode('/',$value);
$sum    = $arr[0]+$arr[1];

//Output
$arr[0] contains 50
$arr[1] contains 20
You can check this by simply doing print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do also something like:

```
$value = '50/20';
$sum = array_sum(explode('/', $value));
echo $sum; // 70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp = explode('/',$value);
$value1 = $exp[0];
$value2 = $exp[1];
$sum = $value1 + $value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = '50/20';
$arr = explode('/',$value);
$num1=$arr[0];
$num2=$arr[1];
$sum=$num1+$num2;
print_r($sum);

Output 
70
```

Explode Function is used to convert a sting to array.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
 $value = "50/20";
 $numbers = preg_split("/\//",$value);
 $sum = $numbers[0]+$numbers[1];
```

Comment: From php.net: `split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.`